# Ramdom com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

we have an application where we use Spring-AMQP to connect to a remote server through AMQP. Lately, and randomly, we are receiving connection errors. These errors occur once or twice a day at different times, and it is beginning to be a major problem. 
The trace that remains in the log is the following:

```
com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.startShutdown(AMQConnection.java:868)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.shutdown(AMQConnection.java:858)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.handleFailure(AMQConnection.java:681)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$400(AMQConnection.java:47)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:582)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:940)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(DataInputStream.java:288)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:91)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:164)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:578)
    ... 1 more
```

I need to get more information about these errors to try to see where the problem is. What do you think that I can look / do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `Connection reset`

Means the client received a RST TCP packet - the socket was closed. First place to look is in the server log. But it might be some other component in the network (firewall, router etc).

Comment: Thanks Gary. I do not have access to the server logs, but I'm trying to monitor the connection with Wireshark, just to try to get more information. Any other idea will be well received. Thanks again